# What does a "distribution" means?

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry, terminology, complex-geometry

This question is the combination of several somehow related questions.

First, Let $M$ be a smooth manifold and $U$ an open subset of $M$. **What does a distribution on $U$ mean?** It seems to be either of the followings

- A continuous linear functional on the space of compact-supported smooth functions on $U$;
- A continuous linear functional on the space of compact-supported smooth densities on $U$.

Second, Let $M$ be a complex manifold and $U$ an open subset of $M$. **What does a (holomorphic?) distribution on $U$ mean?** It seems to be either of the followings

- A continuous linear functional on the space of compact-supported holomorphic functions on $U$;
- A continuous linear functional on the space of compact-supported holomorphic differential forms on $U$ of type $(\dim U, \dim U)$.

Third, Let $X$ be a scheme and $U$ an open subset of $X$. **What does a distribution on $U$ mean?**

Any reference is helpful.

**Update:** I'm actually asking how the sheaf $\mathscr{Db}$ of distributions defined in the above three cases rather than on $\mathbb{R}^n$. In the third case, a "should-be" example is $\Gamma(\mathbb{C}^{\times},\mathscr{Db})=\mathbb{C}[[z,z^{-1}]]$.

Comment: A holomorphic function with compact support must, in particular, be bounded. By Liouville's theorem, such a function must be constant. I doubt that this is what you want.